# In R need know how to identify the second minimum of each unique value, so I can show this data set this other way. Showing just some of the values

Tags: r, minimum

The intention is to produce a data frame with the same number of rows as the original (df), but:

- In df2 I need that in the first minimum of price of each product it shows just the prodcut number and the price in the first row (not the size)
- The following ones, of the same product and same price, I need them to be empty, until the price changes (second minimum of price of each product)
- Then, I need the prodcut, size and price to be shown in each of the following rows until the product changes (except if the size is the same as the supirior row)
- Then start all over again for the following products.
  Below I give you an example of the original data and the one that I'm expecting to get.

```
#original data set

         df<-data.frame(Product=c("6816","6816","6816", 
        "6817","6817","6817","6817","6817","6817", 
        "6818","6818","6818","6818","6818", 
        "6819","6819","6819","6819","6819","6819", 
        "6820","6820","6820","6820","6820","6820", 
        "6821","6821","6821","6821","6821", 
        "6822","6822","6822","6822","6822", 
        "6823","6823","6823","6823","6823","6823","6823", 
        "6824","6824","6824","6824","6824"),
        Size=c("1","2","3",
        "1","2","3","4","5","6",
        "1","2","3","4","5", 
        "1","2","3","4","5","6",
        "1","2","3","4","5","6", 
        "1","2","3","4","5", 
        "1","2","3","4","5", 
        "1","2","3","4","5","6","7", 
        "1","2","3","4","5"),
        Price=c("200","200","200", 
        "400","400","400","500","500","550", 
        "300","300","300","600","650",
        "100", "100", "100", "100","200","200", 
        "150","150","150","150","250","250", 
        "400","400","400","700","750",
        "400","400","400","700","750", 
        "200","200","200","400","400","400","500", 
        "100", "100", "100","100","200"))
```

```
#expected result 
    df2<-data.frame(Product=c("6816","","",
        "6817","","","6817","6817","6817",
        "6818","","","6818","6818"
        "6819","","","","6819","6819,
        "6820","","","","6820","6820",
        "6821","","","6821","6821",
        "6822","","","6822","6822",}
        "6823","","","6823","6823","6823","6823",
        "6824","","","","6824"),
        Size=c("","","",
        "","","","4","5","6",
        "","","","4","5",
        "","","","","5",6",
        "","","","","5","6",
        "","","","4","5",
        "","","","4","5",
        "","","","4","5","6","7",
        "","","","","5",),
        Price=c("200","","",
        "400","","","500","500","550",
        "300","","","600","650",
        "100","","","","200","200",
        "150","","","","250","250",
        "400","","","700,"750",
        "400","","","700,"750",
        "200","","","400","400","400","500",
        "100","","","","200"))
```

Clearly I don´t have enough knowledge to do this, I´ve tried this (with the help of @Paul van Oppen):

```
   Df2 <- df1 %>%select(Product,Size,Price)%>%arrange(Product,Price,as.numeric(Size))%>%
   mutate(Product = if_else(lag(Product, 1) != Product|is.na(lag(Product, 1)),Product,
                    if_else(lag(Product, 1) == Product&lag(Price, 1) == Price,0L,
                    if_else(lag(Product, 1) == Product&lag(Price, 1) != Price&
                        lag(as.factor(Size), 1) != as.factor(Size),Product,0L))))%>%
   mutate(Size = if_else(lag(Product, 1) != Product|is.na(lag(Product, 1)),
                      Size[is.character(Size)]<- '',
                 if_else(lag(Product, 1) == Product&Price==min(Price)&lag(as.factor(Size), 1) !=as.factor(Size),"",
                 if_else(lag(Product, 1) == Product&lag(as.factor(Size), 1) != as.factor(Size)&
                        Price>=min(Price[Price!=min(Price)]), Size,""))))%>%
   mutate(Price = if_else(lag(Product, 1) != Product|is.na(lag(Product, 1)),Price,
                  if_else(lag(Product, 1) == Product&lag(Price, 1) == Price,0L,
                  if_else(lag(Product, 1) == Product&lag(Price, 1) != Price&
                        lag(as.factor(Size), 1) != as.factor(Size),Price,0L))))
```

Thanks

Comment: It is very hard to understand your paragraph description. I would suggest writing it out with bullet points to separate different conditions and hopefully be clearer. Perhaps use some pseudocode.

Comment: Why does row 11 change from `XXL` in the input to `XL` in the output?

Comment: Thanks @GregorThomas, it does just what I needed.  
The mysterious changes of XXL to XL was a mistypping. already correct it. I apologize, I don't know how to narrate the question better, english is not my native language

Comment: After I read it a couple times it made sense. The way you reformatted with bullets helps me a lot too--it just makes it clearer what the steps are.

Answer (score 0):

Except for the mysterious `XXL` to `XL` change in row 11, I think this does what you want:

```
df1 %>%
  mutate(Price_num = as.numeric(Price)) %>%
  arrange(Product, Price) %>% 
  group_by(Product) %>%
  mutate(
    delete_all = coalesce((Price_num == min(Price_num) & row_number() > 1) |
      Size == lag(Size) & Price == lag(Price), FALSE),
    Size = ifelse(row_number() == 1, "", Size)
  ) %>%
  ungroup() %>%
  mutate(across(c(Product, Size, Price), function(x) ifelse(delete_all, "", x))) %>%
  select(Product, Size, Price)
# # A tibble: 11 × 3
#    Product Size  Price
#    <chr>   <chr> <chr>
#  1 "1"     ""    "200"
#  2 ""      ""    ""   
#  3 ""      ""    ""   
#  4 "1"     "XL"  "400"
#  5 "1"     "XXL" "400"
#  6 "2"     ""    "100"
#  7 ""      ""    ""   
#  8 "2"     "L"   "200"
#  9 "2"     "XL"  "200"
# 10 ""      ""    ""   
# 11 "2"     "XXL" "300"
```

Comment: George, i'm sorry to ask you again. but since you published this answer I try to you it and it keeps giving me this two outputs (of note in some datasets"Size" has only numbers) :
1.
       Error: unexpected input in:
"    ungroup() %>%
  mutate(across(c(Artículo, Talle, LISTA1),\"

2.
       Error in UseMethod("select_") : 
  no applicable method for 'select_' applied to an object of class "c('integer', 'numeric')"

Comment: Sounds like you're using and older version of R. R 4.1.0 introduced `\(x)` as a shorthand for `function(x)`. I'll edit my answer to use `function(x)` and that should solve error 1 at least, maybe error 2 as well. If you still have error #2, at least make sure your `dplyr` package version is relatively current.

Comment: Thanks george. that was solve, now it throughs me this: 

        Error: Can't subset columns that don't exist. x Locations 6816, 6817, 6818, 6819, 6820, etc. don't exist.
i There are only 19 columns.

I guess it takes the products number (wich in the data set I tryed goes from 6816 to 6824) as the number of columns. Could you help me?

Comment: Maybe your data has missing values? You could try adding `na.rm = TRUE` to the `min` calls. If you need more help, please find a subset of data that shows the problem you're having and add it to the question. If I can't replicate the problem, all I can do is guess. Also please note my name is Gregor, not George.

Comment: Can you verify that the code works for you on the sample data your provide in the question?

Comment: I´m sorry Gregor, for not reading your name correctly.
There isn't any missing data.
 I´ve tryed the data set I provided and works. 
if I try the actual data set (but with less rows, it also works, but when I use the complete one, in the last step it fails. I'm sending the actual data set in divided coments, because it doesn´t fit in one.
note: for the last step, I replace ir with`df1<- data.frame(df1$Product, df$1Size, df$1Price) and it works

Comment: `df<-data.frame(Product=c("6816","6816","6816",
                          "6817","6817", "6817","6817","6817","6817",
                          "6818","6818","6818","6818","6818",
                          "6819","6819","6819","6819","6819","6819",
                          "6820","6820","6820","6820","6820","6820",
                          "6821","6821","6821","6821","6821",
                          "6822","6822","6822","6822","6822",
                          "6823","6823","6823","6823","6823","6823","6823",
                          "6824","6824","6824","6824","6824"), `

Comment: Please edit the question, not stick things down in comments.

Comment: I've just Done it